# Como pegar o valor de um input e atribuir a outro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Galera tenho um form com vários input que seguem uma sequencia de par, ou seja: valor1 para custo1, valor2 para custo2 e etc...

Preciso pegar o valor do input valor1 e atribuir o mesmo valor para o custo1.

Porém tenho vários inputs e pensem em criar um script onde irei fazer a atribuição, e em cada input eu chamo o evento e informo o nome do input, o script vai e atribui o valor no input desejado.

O problema e que não sei com fazer isso, será que alguém pode me ajudar?

```html
<input type='text' id='valor1' name='valor1'>
<input type='text' id='custo1' name='custo1'>

<br>
<br>

<input type='text' id='valor2' name='valor2'>
<input type='text' id='custo2' name='custo2'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode atualizar o custo referente enquanto digita, por exemplo:

HTML (criar uma classe "valor" e um atributo "custo" para tornar um pouco mais dinâmico):

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".valor").on("input", function(){
            var textoDigitado = $(this).val();
            var inputCusto = $(this).attr("custo");
            $("#"+ inputCusto).val(textoDigitado);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='valor1' class='valor' name='valor1' custo='custo1'>
<input type='text' id='custo1' name='custo1' >

<input type='text' id='valor2' class='valor' name='valor2' custo='custo2'><br>
<input type='text' id='custo2' name='custo2' >
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: bom tenho mais uma dúvida, sem querer abusar mais vc pode me ajudar? criei um input chamado custo, onde vou informar um valor, depois tenho os inputs chamado valor e margem, onde eu vou digitar um valor na margem em % e ele vai preencher o valor com base no custo. Teria como me ajudar? Segue o código:https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/2/

Comment: Qual seria o calculo?

Comment: ok, seria assim: eu iria informar o custo, logo apos eu iria informar uma % no campo margem, o java tem que pegar o custo ver qual o valor atualizado com base na margem de lucro e colocar no campo valor correspondente. Exemplo do calculo em java: {var valor_magem = Math.round(custo * margem) / 100; var novo_valor = custo + valor_agem;}

Comment: Veja se é isso: https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/5/

Comment: isso mesmo :) amigo ficou muito bom. So mais uma coisa, e possível ele fazer o inverso tbm? tipo se eu informar um valor ele me fala qual a margem de lucro obtido. tem como?

Comment: Tem sim. https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/6/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35931/discussion-between-hugo-sabrina-and-joao-paulo).

Comment: legal, mas o que eu queria saber e se tem como manter as duas formas juntas, ou seja ao mesmo tempo. se eu informar o margem ele gera o valor, se eu informar o valor ele gera a margem. Isso e possível?

Comment: Sim é só mesclar os dois ultimos fiddles. https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/7/

Comment: amigo, ficou muito bom. código ficou muito simples. Obrigado e parabéns.

Comment: so mais uma dúvida hahaha. estou tentando fazer ele escrever o valor no padrão pt-br, ou seja: 400,33. tentei o seguinte: {inputValor = inputValor.toString().replace('.', ',');} mas não deu certo, tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7aq46h0x/8/

Comment: perfeito, funcionou 100%

Comment: poderia me dar uma ajuda com este problema aqui? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115916/problema-ao-formatar-números-com-javascript

Comment: olá sem querer abusar, teria como me dar uma ajuda com esta questão aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116529/como-resolver-problema-de-cálculo-de-margem-no-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Basta definir a propriedade `value` do elemento:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');

b.value = a.value;
```

```html
<input id='a' type='text' value='StackOverflow'/>
<input id='b' type='text'/>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda :)