# Como resolver problema de cálculo de margem no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tenho o seguintes inputs:

1º Custo, onde eu informo o valor de `6,23`
2º Margem, onde eu informo o valor de `29,21`

O `JavaScript` faz o cálculo automático e me retorna `8,05` no valor

Bom esta tudo correto. Porém quando faço ao contrário acontece o erro.

1º Custo, onde eu informo o valor de `6,23`
2º Valor, onde eu informo o valor de `8,05`

O `JavaScript` faz o calculo automático e me retorna `36.44` na margem, sendo que o correto seria `29,21`

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Segue o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".valor").on("input", function () {
        // Margem
        var valor = $(this).val();
        var valorCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valor));
           
        var valorFloat = parseFloat(valorCorrigido) || 0.0;

        // Custo  
        var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
        var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
        var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0;

        // Calculo
        var calculo = (parseFloat(valorFloat) - parseFloat(valorCustoFloat)) / parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * 100;
        var inputMargem = $(this).attr("margem");

        $("#" + inputMargem).val(calculo.toFixed(2)).trigger('blur');
    });
    // Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
    $(".margem").on("input", function () {
        // Margem
        var valorMargem = $(this).val();  
        var valorMargemCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valorMargem));
        var valorMargemFloat = parseFloat(valorMargemCorrigido) || 0.0; 

        // Custo
        var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
        var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
        var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0; 

        // Cálculo
        var calculo = (parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * parseFloat(valorMargemFloat) / 100) + parseFloat(valorCustoFloat);
        var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");

        var resultadoMonetario = calculo.toFixed(2).toString();
        resultadoMonetario = resultadoMonetario.replace(".", ",");

        $("#" + inputValor).val(resultadoMonetario).trigger('blur');
    });

    function removerPontos(valor){
        valor = valor.replace(".","");
        valor = valor.replace(",",".");
        return valor;           
    }
    
    function adicionarPontos(valor){
       if(valor.length == 1){
           return valor;
       }
       else{
       if(valor.length == 2){
           return valor;
       }
       else{
       valor = valor.replace(",","");
      var inteiro = valor.substring(0,valor.length - 2);
       
       console.log(inteiro);
       
       var decimal = valor.substr(2);
       
       console.log(inteiro + "." + decimal);
       return inteiro + "." + decimal;
       }
       }
    }
});

$('input').mask('00.000.000,00', {
    reverse: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.js"></script>


Custo:
<input type='text' id='custo' class='custo valores' name='custo'>
<br>
<br> Valor:
<input type='text' id='valor1' class='valor valores' name='valor1' margem='margem1'> Margem:
<input type='text' id='margem1' class='margem valores' name='margem1' valor="valor1">

<br> Valor:
<input type='text' id='valor2' class='valor valores' name='valor2' margem='margem2'> Margem:
<input type='text' id='margem2' class='margem valores' name='margem2' valor="valor2">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um erro na função adicionarPontos:

O correto é:

```
 var inteiro = valor.substring(0,valor.length - 2);
 var decimal = valor.substring(valor.length - 2, valor.length);
```

Todos os trechos "console.log" podem ser removidos. São usados apenas para debugar.

Comment: como sempre muito obrigado.