# Copiar valor de um Textarea para Outro Automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu vi esse post ([Como pegar o valor de um input e atribuir a outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113978/como-pegar-o-valor-de-um-input-e-atribuir-a-outro)
) mas não consegui adaptar para o `textarea`.

Eu tenho o seguinte HTML, que quero passar o valor do primeiro textarea para o segundo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">

             <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textoOriginal">Insira seu Texto</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="texto" class="texto" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="textoConvertido">Insira seu Texto</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="convertido1" name="convertido1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o jQuery, é só fazer assim:

```js
$(function () {

    $('#texto').on('input', function () {
         $('#convertido1').val(this.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textoOriginal">Insira seu Texto</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="texto" class="texto" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="textoConvertido">Insira seu Texto</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="convertido1" name="convertido1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim usando `jquery`

```js
$('#one').on('keyup', function(){
  var valor = $(this).val()
  $('#two').val(valor)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

Ou tambem pode fazer usando apenas `javascript`

```js
let one = document.getElementById('one')
let two = document.getElementById('two')

one.onkeyup = function(){
  let valor = one.value
  two.value = valor
}
```

```html
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

E claro, que tem varias formas de se fazer isso, com `click` e etc. Use conforme sua necessidade.